# Strategy to get X many users that have visited any pages that directly link to the current page

Tags: users, user-engagement, concurrent-users

Forums have a "x many users online". And "X views" on each threads. What I want is how many users have visited the pages that link directly to the thread in place of "X views". Sort of combining the two features to give a better information.

What's the best way to achieve this? (I'm familiar with wordpress and drupal)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If an external site links to yours, you generally have no way of knowing how many visitors the page linking to you gets.  If it is your own page, you can measure it by counting hits in your log files.